# Dúvida de loop(For) com informações vindo do banco de dados

Tags: php, foreach, for, while

E ae pessoal blz ?

Estou com um grande problema na execução de um código meu.

Tenho uma aplicação web feita em laravel, que está rodando local. Nessa aplicação preciso gerar um relatório que está sendo feito utilizando DOMPDF.

O relatório está incompleto. Não estou conseguindo fazer a lógica de programação para ele funcionar 100% da maneira que eu quero.

Vou explicar abaixo o cenário para vocês entenderem melhor para me ajudar.

Tenho que gerar um relatório onde imprima todos os dados de comparecimento do mês dos funcionários da empresa. Portanto, cada página é necessário ter um cabeçalho para assinatura do responsável.
Além disso, é necessário a divisão dos funcionários por departamento, ou seja, se eu tiver 100 funcionários e 10 departamentos, preciso que toda vez que houver a mudança de funcionário com departamento diferente ele inicie uma nova página, ou quando atingir o número de 16 funcionários por página.

EX: Igual na Imagem abaixo, o relatório teria que imprimir os funcionários 1 ao 16, quebrar de página e começar imprimir do 17 ao 21, nova quebra de página porque o funcionário mudou de departamento e assim sucessivamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não estou conseguindo fazer é o for voltar a imprimir de onde parou quando existe uma lista de mais de 16 funcionários por departamento.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Segue meu código abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Relatório Geral</title>
    <style>

        body {
            margin-top: -20px;
            margin-left: -20px;
            margin-right: -5px;
            padding:0
        }

        .borda3 {
            border:1px solid #999;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #borda2 td {
            border: 1px solid #999;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: auto;

        }

        .centro {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .tabela {
            width: 100%;
        }

        span {
            font-size: 100px;
        }

        td {
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        html {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        #customers {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #customers td, #customers th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;

        }

        #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

        #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

        #customers th {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 9px;
        }

        #customers td {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        #customers a {
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .nome{
            width: 180px;
        }

        .matricula{
            width: 15px;
        }

        .numeros{
            width: 15px;
        }

        .logo{
            padding-left: 50px;

        }

        .logo a strong{
            font-size: 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .logo a{
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .assinatura{
            font-size: 9px;
            margin-left: 60px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
@for($i=0; $i< $aux; $i++)
    @php
    {{$j=0;}}
    @endphp
    <body>
        <table class="tabela borda3">
            <tr>
                <td width="40%" class="centro">
                    <table class="logo">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img style="margin-left:20px; margin-top: -20px;width:220px; height: 65px;" src="img/logo_sarh.jpg">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for=""><a><strong> </strong></a></label><br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a>Referência:</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a>Período:</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="40%" class="centro">
                    <table class="assinatura">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 30px; text-align: left"><label for="">Em: _____/ _____/___________</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: -20px; height: 50px; text-align: center">
                                <label for="">____________________________________________</label><br>
                             <label style="font-size: 10px" for=""> SUPERVISOR</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 30px; text-align: left"><label for="">VISTO</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: -10px; height: 50px; text-align: center">
                                <label for="">____________________________________________</label><br>
                                <label style="font-size: 10px" for=""> SECRETÁRIO(A)</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table id="customers">
            <tr>
                <th class="nome">Nome</th>
                <th class="matricula">Matrícula</th>
                <th class="numeros">Dias</th>
                <th class="numeros">Faltas</th>
                <th class="numeros">Vac</th>
                <th class="numeros">LSV</th>
                <th class="numeros">L M</th>
                <th class="numeros">Aci. Trab</th>
                <th class="numeros">Adi. Not</th>
                <th class="numeros">H.E Normal D</th>
                <th class="numeros">H.E Normal N</th>
                <th class="numeros">H.E Dom/Fer. D</th>
                <th class="numeros">H.E Dom/Fer. N</th>
                <th class="numeros">Ins.</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach ($servidores[$i] as $servidor)
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>{{$servidor->nm_servidor}}</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>{{$servidor->cd_departamento}}</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>30</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20,02</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20,02</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20,02</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20,02</a></td>
                    <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 20px;" colspan="14">Observação:</td>
                </tr>
                @if($j == 16)
                    @break
                @endif
                @php
                    {{$j++;}}
                @endphp
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </body>
@endfor
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que uma solução será você agrupar por departamento e assim percorrer os dois loops (departamentos, membros por departamento).

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
@foreach ($departamentos as $departamento)
   @foreach ($departamento->funcionarios as $funcionario)
     <html>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Espero ter ajudado!